# Using ggplot geom_histogram() with y-log-scale with zero bins

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, logarithm

I've got a set with >10000 integers attaining values between 1 and 500. 
I want to plot the values in form of a histogram, however, since only a few integers attain values greater than 200, I want to use a logarithmic scale for the y-axis.

A problem emerges, when one bin has a count of zero, since the logarithmic value goes to -infinity.

To avoid this, I want to add a pseudocount of 1 to each bin. 
In a standard hist()-plot I can do this like follows:

```
hist.data = hist(data, plot=F, breaks=30)
hist.data$counts = log10(hist.data$counts + 1)
plot(hist.data, ...)
```

However, I struggle to find a way to access the counts in ggplot.

Is there a simple way to do this, or are there other recommended ways to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to write your own transformation function for the y scale. Transformations functions used by ggplot2 (when using `scale_y_log10()` for instance) are defined in the `scales` package.

### Short answer

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

mylog10_trans <- function (base = 10) 
{
  trans <- function(x) log(x + 1, base)
  inv <- function(x) base^x
  trans_new(paste0("log-", format(base)), trans, inv, log_breaks(base = base), 
            domain = c(1e-100, Inf))
}

ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_histogram() + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "mylog10")
```

output

[image]

data used for this figure:

```
df <- data.frame(x=sample(1:100, 10000, replace = TRUE))
df$x[sample(1:10000, 50)] <- sample(101:500, 50)
```

### Explaining the trans function

Let's examine `scales::log10_trans`; it calls `scales::log_trans()`; now, `scales::log_trans`prints as:

```
function (base = exp(1)) 
{
    trans <- function(x) log(x, base)
    inv <- function(x) base^x
    trans_new(paste0("log-", format(base)), trans, inv, log_breaks(base = base), 
        domain = c(1e-100, Inf))
}
<environment: namespace:scales>
```

In the answer above, I replaced:

```
trans <- function(x) log(x, base)
```

with:

```
trans <- function(x) log(x + 1, base)
```

Comment: Can I somehow avoid that the counts 0 and 1 will be equal on the scale?

Comment: yes, just replace `ifelse(x > 0, log(x, base), 0)` with `log(x + 1, base)` ; see my edit

Comment: Many thanks, that helped alot! 
One last question: Can I somehow adjust the y-axis labels? (since they now tick at 1, 11, 1001, ...)

Comment: EDIT: I sort of cheated an set breaks manually at desired positions using breaks=c(10-1, 100-1, 1000-1, 10000-1). 
In my case, this solution is good enough.

Comment: There is now `scales::log1p_trans()` (-> `log(x + 1)`), which can be used like so: `scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::log1p_trans()`. See also `pseudo_log_trans()`.