# ggplot2 and log scale don't show values = 1

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

I want to plot a diagram with a log scales y axis:

```
data <- data.frame(x = seq_len(5), y = c(2,1,100,500,30))
ggplot(data) + aes(x,y) + geom_col() + scale_y_log10()
```

But because the horizontal axis always crosses the vertical axis at y = 1, the bar for y = 1 is never drawn.

[image]

I know that log(1) = 0, but can I set the plot base to 0.1 to let the bar start below 1?

Comment: We can cheat a bit: `ggplot(data) + aes(x, y + 0.1) + geom_col() + scale_y_log10()`

Comment: I think I'm missing the point here. The graph is correct: the values on the Y axis are log-transofrmed, hence zero becomes 1; `log10(1)` is zero, so it's correct you can't see bar 2. What's your goal?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/40219639/680068

Comment: One option is to force a line round the bars - e.g. `geom_col(colour = "grey20")`, so that you at least get a line at y=1.

Comment: Another related post https://stackoverflow.com/q/41849951/680068

Comment: I think the only way without doing much of programming is to set the color as @AndrewGustar wrote. I also have some histograms, so "cheating" is not possible without doing all the calculation by hand.

Comment: @StefanL. no, that's not true, because the y scale will take a label transforming function. See my answer to show this working with `geom_histogram`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just multiply the values of y by 10 but divide the labels by the same amount?

```r
ggplot(data) + aes(x, y * 10) +  geom_col() + 
  scale_y_log10(labels = function(x) x/10, name = "y")
```

[image]

You could do the same with a histogram:

```r
set.seed(2)
ggplot(data.frame(x = rnorm(1000)), aes(x)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count.. * 10), color = "black", fill = "gold") +
  scale_y_log10(labels = function(x) x/10, name = "count")
```

[image]

Comment: That's a good idea and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to place the bottom of the bars at `-Inf`, so that the `log10(1)` still shows up. This is a bit tricky, because you have to reparameterise the bars as rectangles and get the geom to understand that the `-Inf` is after scale transformation.

```r
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(x = seq_len(5), y = c(2,1,100,500,30))

ggplot(data) + 
  geom_rect(
    aes(xmin = x - 0.45, xmax = x + 0.45,
        ymin = stage(1, after_scale = -Inf), ymax = y)
  ) +
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It's not only geom_col I want to print, but also histograms. Your solution is drawing the boxes by hand, but if I want to use the histogram calculation, this won't work. I hoped for a small parameter I didn't find so far.